# SGE+ sqlite3 : Error: database is locked

Tags: sqlite, locking, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I'm trying to run a script that uses **sqlite3** in a cluster (**SGE**).

The script creates a lock with [lockfile](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_lockfile.htm), fills the database and releases the lock.

```
  $cat test.sh

  #!/bin/sh
  lockfile /commun/data/_tmp.idp448.lock
  sqlite3 /commun/data/stats.sqlite "create table if not exists timeBeginDB(target text UNIQUE NOT NULL,inserted int);"
  rm -f /commun/data/_tmp.idp448.lock
  whoami
```

the  /commun/data/ is visible from all the nodes. /commun/data/_tmp.idp448.lock is a random name I've created, I'm currently the only one using our new cluster.

without qsub the script works without any problem :

```
  [lindenb]$ sh test.sh
  lindenb #prints whoami, no error on stderr
```

when **qsub** is invoked:

```
  $ qsub -cwd -S /bin/sh test.sh
  Your job 673 ("test.sh") has been submitted

  $ cat test.sh.o673
  lindenb #prints 'whoami', so the lock have been created and deleted


  $ cat test.sh.e673
  Error: database is locked
```

which is a sqlite3 error.

Do you have any idea, suggestion of what, on the SGE side, could be the cause of that problem, this difference of behavior ?

Thank you
Pierre

**UPDATE:**

I've logged as root on a node of the cluster. The simple following command fails:
(/commun/data/stats2.sqlite doesn't exist)

```
ssh root@node02
root@node02's password:
sqlite3 /commun/data/stats2.sqlite 'create table if not exists timeBeginDB(target text UNIQUE NOT NULL,inserted int);'
Error: database is locked
```

it works in ~root:

```
[root@node02 ~]# sqlite3 stats2.sqlite 'create table if not exists timeBeginDB(target text UNIQUE NOT NULL,inserted int);'
[root@node02 ~]#
```

Comment: Does the error happen with `for i in {1..10} ; do test.sh & done` ?

Comment: @choroba, I've run the loop, there is no error on stderr.

Answer (score 1):

From the tests I did on our SGE, it seems `lockfile` does not work over the cluster. What seems to work, though, is a simple `mkdir` lock described at [bash-hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex).

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/commun/data/
LOCK=$DIR/_tmp.idp448.lock
until mkdir $LOCK ; do
    sleep 4
done
(date ; hostname) >> $DIR/sge-test
rmdir $LOCK
whoami
```

With `lockfile`, the dates reported in the sge-test file are very close to each other.

Comment: @Pierre: Have you tried your script with `(date ; hostname)` instead of `sqlite3` to verify the `lockfile` really works?

Comment: I've updated my question, It's a problem with sqlite, not lockfile

Answer (score 1):

Is /commun/data an NFS mount on your exec nodes?

One reason you may be likely to see the SQLite "Error: database is locked" message in GridEngine setups, which often have many nodes writing to a shared filesystem over NFS, is that SQLite wants to use fcntl locks which just plain *don't work right* over NFSv3 unless you're running lockd on both the client and the server.

I run in to this a lot, and in every case I've seen so far simply enabling the lockd(or rpc.lockd, or nfslock, etc, depending on your environment) service on each cluster node and whatever machine is serving the shared filesystem will resolve the issue.